# Delay in bluetooth communication with the printer - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, printing, bluetooth, thermal-printer

I am trying to establish a connection with the bluetooth printer using [DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android](https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android) and it works perfectly fine. However I see some delay with the moment the code is executed and the moment until the paper is printed which is few seconds. For instance the print request is initiated in real time but, printer takes (I am not sure whether the bluetooth socket) few seconds (3-5 seconds) to print.

Then I implemented some logic to connect to the bluetooth socket manually using

```
 fun connectToBluetoothDeviceSync(device: BluetoothDevice,
                                      callback: (isConnected: Boolean, socket: BluetoothSocket?, error: String?) -> Unit) {
        try {
            val uuid: String = when(getDeviceType(device)) {
                DeviceType.PRINTER -> device.uuids[0].uuid.toString()
            }
            val bluetoothSocket: BluetoothSocket? = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                ParcelUuid.fromString(uuid).uuid
            )
            bluetoothSocket?.connect()
            callback(bluetoothSocket?.isConnected == true, bluetoothSocket, null)
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            logE("Bluetooth Device Connect Async Error: ${e.message}")
            callback(false, null, e.message ?: "Couldn't connect")
        }
    }
```

And yet it takes some time to connect but it differs from time to time. Sometimes it connects within 1 second, or takes few seconds or else gets a timeout after around 10 seconds. But however the code gets executed within a matter of few milliseconds, but the printer takes time to print the data. Is it normal that the bluetooth thermal printer communication takes such delay while IP, and USB printers print within 1-2s?

Answer (score 1):

Entirely depends on the printer.  The printer itself may not instantly start printing.  It may wait in case more data is coming and need to time out.  It may need to clean the print head.  It may need to warm up the thermals.  There's lots of reasons why printing may not be automatic that have nothing to do with the code on the mobile side.  It doesn't even mean the printer isn't reacting to the data-  it may just need to do something else before it prints.  If you say it prints within a few seconds I'd call that good enough.

Comment: But I am using the same printer for IP, and USB communication but it doesn't takes a delay at all. So why is the bluetooth communication takes time?

Comment: It seems that devices communicating via bluetooth have a mode in which the functions of several internal units are stopped individually in order to save power. It may take some time to restore them to operational status.